# Extracting a string and removing Whitespace

Tags: regex

I want to extract the string between GROSS and kg and remove whitespace in this text :

```
ID.NO.  123456
DATE    02/05/21
TIME    01:52 AM
GROSS-   13.5 kg
TARE      0.0 kg
NET  -   13.5 kg
```

my best result yet is  `(?<=GROSS)(.*)(?=kg)` with the result is `-   13.5`

still need to remove the whitespace.

Comment: Where are you using the regex? What programming language?

Comment: You can use 2 capture groups and match the space in between `\bGROSS(\S+)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) kg\b` https://regex101.com/r/UAlh6O/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 capture groups and match the whitespace in between.

Then you can concatenate group 1 and group 2 to get `-13.5`

```
\bGROSS(\S*)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+kg\b
```

*Explanation*

- `\bGROSS` A word boundary and match `GROSS`
- `(\S*)` Capture **group 1**, optionally match 0 or more following non whitespace chars
- `\s+` Match 1 or more whitespace chars
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 2**, match 1 or more digits with an optional decimal part
- `\s+kg\b` Match 1 or more whitespace chars, `kg` and a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fdsiiR/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
(?<=GROSS\D*)(\d.*?)(?=\s*kg)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/PBUuXM/1)

Or, use

```php
GROSS\D*\K\d.*?(?=\s*kg)
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/PBUuXM/2/).

**Explanation**

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `GROSS` | 'GROSS' |
| `\D*` | non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\d` | digits (0-9) |
| `.*?` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `\s*` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `kg` | 'kg' |

Comment: I need to keep the minus sign, i was able to do with only the numbers but not with - and numbers without spaces.